# Use Aggregate Function on Unnested Array in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to use Postgres [var_samp()](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-aggregate.html) function on multiple columns in my db and want to do it without subqueries/CTEs, desire speed.

I've tried this:

```
select
var_samp(array[obs1,obs2]) as varsample
    from my_table
```

Tried this based off another [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/241991), couldn't get it to work (I'm sure I'm the issue):

```
select
var_samp(my_col)
    from (select unnest(array[obs1, obs2])as my_col from my_table)
```

I've had success is using CTEs, but trying to avoid them:

```
WITH cte_raw_data as (
        select
            unnest(array[obs1, obs2])as my_col
        from my_table
        ),
cte_var_samp as (
        select
            var_samp(my_col) as my_var_samp
        from cte_raw_data   
)
SELECT * FROM cte_var_samp
```

`my_table` data below, thank you for helping me:

| "obs1" | "obs2" |
| --- | --- |
| 74.002 | 74.03 |
| 73.992 | 73.995 |
| 74.024 | 73.988 |
| 73.996 | 74.002 |
| 74.007 | 73.992 |
| 73.994 | 74.009 |
| 74.006 | 73.995 |
| 74.003 | 73.985 |
| 73.995 | 74.008 |
| 74 | 73.998 |
| 73.998 | 73.994 |
| 74 | 74.004 |
| 74.002 | 73.983 |
| 73.967 | 74.006 |
| 74.014 | 74.012 |
| 73.984 | 74 |
| 74.012 | 73.994 |
| 74.01 | 74.006 |
| 74.002 | 73.984 |
| 74.01 | 74 |
| 74.001 | 73.988 |
| 73.999 | 74.004 |
| 73.989 | 74.01 |
| 74.008 | 74.015 |
| 73.984 | 73.982 |

Comment: You say "*trying to avoid CTES*" and "*desire speed*", but these have nothing to do with each other. Nested subqueries or CTEs are just a way to express a query, which may be executed in exactly the same way as an equivalent JOIN. Inspect the query plan if you really care about speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify that query to

```
WITH cte_raw_data AS (
    SELECT unnest(array[obs1, obs2]) AS my_col
    FROM my_table
)
SELECT var_samp(my_col) AS my_var_samp
FROM cte_raw_data;
```

or

```
SELECT var_samp(my_col) AS my_var_samp
FROM (
    SELECT unnest(array[obs1, obs2]) AS my_col
    FROM my_table
) AS cte_raw_data;
```

but really you just want to use [`unnest` as a lateral table function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLEFUNCTIONS):

```
SELECT var_samp(my_col) AS my_var_samp
FROM my_table, unnest(array[obs1, obs2]) AS my_col;
```

Notice that all these queries are doing the same thing and will have the same query plan and same execution speed.